# Find and replace all occurrences not in quotes

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm in the middle of refactoring my Python code to use underscore notation as described in PEP8 and I am using VS Code's find-and-replace tool. The problem is occurrences of words in quotes are also being replaced. How can I replace all occurrences that aren't in quotes?

Example:

```
fooBar = df["fooBar"]
```

Desired after find and replace

```
foo_bar = df["fooBar"]
```

Comment: you the refactor of variables, place cursor on variable and press `F2`

Comment: Tried this out, it was able the change the name of a variable without changing the fooBar in quotes but it didn't refactor all other instances. Is there a way to make this work all other instances in the document simultaneously?

Comment: if you have the correct language server it should change all instances of the variable, if you place the cursor on the variable name it will highlight the other instances

Answer (score -1, accepted):

open the find-and-replace vscode tool(ctrl+f and ctrl+h)

1. select the `User Regular Expression(Alt+R)`
2. select the `Match Case (Alt+c)`
3. Find  = `([a-z]*)(?<!_)([A-Z])(?<!".*)`
4. Replace = `$1_\L$2`

finaly press Enter

[image: find-and-replace]

result is :
[image: reult]

Answer (score 1):

VS Code's Search functions supports regex, and you can use a [negative lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind) pattern to find "*all fooBar strings that are not preceded by a quote*": `(?<!")fooBar`.

[image]

(1) enables regex expressions when searching. As you can see, that ignores all the `"fooBar"` instances. Then you can also turn on (2) so that it enables whole word matching (so that it doesn't match "fooBar123").

As a side note, I hope you have automated tests you can run after doing all these renaming :)